# flink MultipleLinearRegression fit take 3 params

Tags: apache-flink, flinkml

I follow the example of 
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/batch/libs/ml/multiple_linear_regression.html
but in the example the fit function only need one param,but in my code , fit require three params,

mlr.fit(training, fitParameters, fitOperation);

I thought fitParameters may be a alternative for setIterations(),setStepsize()
but what is fitOperation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fitOperation` parameter is actually an implicit parameter which is filled in automatically by the Scala compiler. It encapsulates the MLR logic.

Since your `fit` function has 3 parameters, I suspect that you're using FlinkML with Flink's Java API. I would highly recommend you using the Scala API, because otherwise you will have to construct the ML pipelines manually. If you still want to do it, then take a look at the `FitOperations` defined in the `MultipleLinearRegression` companion object.